# Backbone view as part of an unordered or ordered html list

Tags: javascript, html, css, backbone.js

I have a problem - I have a list:

```
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
</ol>
```

This part is static and will never change.

Another button adds a Backbone view to this list without grouping it.

As you know; you need an el tag on a view or at the very least a root tag as I may need to do further event capture on this view. I cannot use a div tag as the resulting html would be invalid, this:

```
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <div class="myBackboneView">
        <li>List item for first component</li>
        <li>List item for second component</li>
    </div>
</ol>
```

(Cannot have div tags amongst those li)

Does anyone know of how I might be able to sneak a root tag without messing the html validation up.

Either that or is there a backbone trick that allows you to have a view linked together without using an el.

I'd also want to be able to add any number of these views - so I'd have a root view rooted to the ol tag and then within that view it would delegate to individual views for each of the li groups and so the problem is that I can't put a tag to group those li tags.

I know you might think it should be a separate list but this is a list of things to do. If they add this new view they have more things to do in the list - thus it makes sense for it to be part of one list.

Thanks for any help - I'm off to make meatballs.

Comment: you can change the tagName property in your view to `ol`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li class="myBackboneView">
      <ol>
        <li>List item for first component</li>
        <li>List item for second component</li>
      <ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

You could also put `class="myBackboneView"` on the inner `ol`.

Comment: Problem with this though is that it would be a separate inner list. Ideally I'd want it as one list. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) to set your view's `el` to a specific element that already exists:

> **setElement** `view.setElement(element)`
>
> If you'd like to apply a Backbone view to a different DOM element, use **setElement**, which will also create the cached `$el` reference and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one.

So you can simply do this somewhere convenient (such as `initialize` or `render`):

```
this.setElement($('ol'));
```

You might need a more specific selector of course.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mTX6K/

You could also set [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) manually in your view's definition:

```
el: 'ol' // Or a more specific selector
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qk5Tg/1/

Comment: Thanks for this, only what I'd like is to be able to add any number of these views on to this list. I agree with you with there being a view centered on the list but ideally I'd want a number of them within that root view. I'll update my question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: You can't do it with an `<ol>` as the only thing you can put inside an `<ol>` is an `<li>` and Backbone wants one element per view. You might be able to have one view per `<li>` though. Or find an element that is more flexible than an `<ol>`.

Comment: Ah okay thanks anyway if there's no other solutions I'll accept your answer. Specifically your last comment.

Comment: The problem is that `<ol>` and `<ul>` don't have any analogue to `<table>`'s `<tbody>` element so you can't group the `<li>`s by slipping something between the `<li>`s and the `<ol>`. Bummer.